# How to pass to the AngularJS $resource query callback function the reference to the parent object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app, with a scope. Inside this scope there an array of Content objects, displayed through a view. In the view, for each content, there's a button Select, connected to the object's method selectToggle().

When this method is called, a $resource that will post some informations to an API, is created. 
In the $resource.query callback I need to access the parent Content object, but since it's asynchronous, I loose the reference ('this' is not pointing to the Window object).

How can I pass a reference to the object who create the $resource in the callback function?

Thanks

```
function Content (informations) {

    this.selected = false;
    this.spinnerEnabled = false;
    this.error = null;

    this.selectToggle = function () {

        this.spinnerEnabled = true;

        ContentResource = $resource(
            '/en/api/content',
            null,
            {'query': {'method': 'POST', isArray: false}}
        ).query({
            'type':             this.type,
            'extId':            this.id

        }, function (response) {

            // Here this is pointing to Window, not to the Content object
            // so the following set are useless.

            if (response.status == "success") {
                this.selected = ! this.selected;
            } else if (response.status == "error") {
                this.error = response.message;
            } else {
                this.error = "Request failed";
            }

            this.spinnerEnabled = false;
        });
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store a reference to the `Content` object as such:

```
function Content (informations) {
   this.selected = false;
   this.spinnerEnabled = false;
   this.error = null;

   var self = this; // <-- Store reference for use later
   // ...
```

Then, in your callback you can refer to `self`:

```
if (response.status == "success") {
   self.selected = ! self.selected;
} else if (response.status == "error") {
   self.error = response.message;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. And especially for replying in less than a minute!

Comment: You can also refer my following question which has answer of this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517872/how-to-read-response-from-angular-resource-save-and-also-keeping-original-dat